# macos bash script reading file but get access denied

Tags: bash, macos, file, privileges, cat

This is about bash under macos Catalina but should run under Big Sur too.

I want to fill a variable with the content of an HTML file and filter it later with grep.

Only I get for the HTML file access denied.

As a test, I use

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

$cat "./omnikresponse.html"  #(it doesn't matter whether I use the whole path or not).
```

The file has the following privileges.

> 16 -rw-r--r--@ 1 la staff  6384 Dec 15 17:23 omnikresponse.html
>
> com.apple.TextEncoding    15
>
> com.apple.lastuseddate#PS     16
>
> com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags   42
>
> com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_yjfxnnrt6pupmoito5lwf3xyea    89
>
> com.dropbox.attrs     26
>
> de.codingmonkeys.seestate     92

In the security settings, the terminal has 'full disk access'.
The script runs as the user and sits in the same folder as the HTML file.
I can set the HTML file to 755 and then I have access but it is not really wanted for security reasons I guess.

How can I solve this? Why do I have to change the privileges for just reading the file?

Comment: Your program would only make sense, if `cat` is an environment variable, and has been set to a suitable value in one of the child processes.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `$cat` contains the name of a program you want to run on the file, the problem is that the shell (rightly) thinks you are trying to *execute* this file, as if it were a script or a binary.

In case it's not obvious, the `$` you see in many beginners' tutorials is not part of what you are supposed to type into the computer; it is a placeholder for the prompt the computer (or rather the shell) displays when it is ready to receive a command from you in the terminal.

To spell this out, `$cat` refers to the value of the variable `cat`; if it is undefined or contains the empty string, your script can be reduced to

```sh
./omnikresponse.html
```

(Points for the quoting, but it's not really necessary here. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable). If you really wanted to refer to the variable `$cat`, probably *that* should have been in double quotes.)

And so in still other words, I'm guessing your script should be

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cat ./omnikresponse.html
```

... which of course doesn't actually make sense to put in a script at all; just type

```sh
cat ./omnikresponse.html
```

directly at the Bash prompt.

(If you are beginner, chances are that you are actually using Zsh, not Bash. The default shell for new users since MacOS Catalina is Zsh; in previous versions, it used to be Bash. But this answer probably works for both.  ... If it works. I had to guess several things.)